# How can I include owl carousel If I don't wont host the library file

Tags: javascript, jquery, include, owl-carousel

I want to include owl carousel library to my site, but I do not want to download files. In https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/ or in internet I did not find the way to do it. 
It means I want to include it as an external library like I can do it for jquery library

Comment: YOU CAN USE THIS: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/owl-carousel

Comment: Thank you David) I do not know can I trust cdnjs.com or not , but works thank you )

Comment: of course you can trust cdnjs.com... its being used by millions of other websites and web application all over the world.